# How to apply multiple between operator in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a journal type table where it has `Account`, `Credit_Debit` and `Amount` columns. I am trying a 
`select` where by the result should look like a row followed by its contra amount row. Amount column is Numeric/Decimal.

Expected output: An amount followed by its equivalent opposite(plus or minus) amount

```
expected output

|Account|c_d|Amount|
| 1     |D  | 100  |
! 7     |C  | -100 |
| 8     |D  | 750  |
| 1     |C  | -750 |
| 10    |C  | -500 |
| 11    |D  | 500  |
```

So, my query below threw invalid relational operator

```
select * from table where amount between 100 and 1000 AND (-100) - (-1000)
```

This one returned empty result set

```
select * from table where 
 (amount between('100') AND ('1000')) AND (amount between('-100') AND ('-1000'))
```

Comment: Is the presented sample of data expected output(looks like it) or the source data? If it's expected result, it'll be a good idea to post a sample of source data.

Comment: I think you have to change the `AND` in middle of the `amount` statements to `OR`.

Comment: `between('100') AND ('1000'))` is really bad coding style. First numbers should **not** be enclosed in single quotes. `'100'` is a character literal (aka "string"), not a number. `100` is a number literal. Secondly: the parentheses around the numbers `('-100')` useless.

Comment: Is the AMOUNT column a character string, or is it a NUMBER? In the last comparison you've made the literal values all character string by putting them inside apostrophes. If AMOUNT is a character string you're probably going to have real problems getting your comparisons to work.

Comment: Updated the question with datatype and expected output

Comment: Thanks for adding the data type information. I suggest that you remove the apostrophes around the literals in your second query. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this has worked.  Thanks for everyone's efforts.

```
select * from table where amount between 100 AND 1000
UNION
select * from table where amount between -1000 AND -100
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second one will work with an OR operator.

```
select * from table where (amount between('100') AND ('1000')) OR (amount between('-100') AND ('-1000'))
```

But it will show rows containing amounts between -1000 and 1000 minus those with amounts between -100 and 100.

To do what you want to do, if I get it right, you can sue:

```
SELECT T1.amount, T2.amount from table T1, table T2 WHERE ABS(T1.amount) = ABS(T2.amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from table where 
 (amount between('100') AND ('1000')) AND (amount between('-1000') AND ('-100'))
```

Comment: Please could you read my question and the things I have tried

Comment: Use OR not AND while joining the two where clauses.